# Wordpress Site not loading framework

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site at www.ironcowboy.co.  For some reason when you load the site there are times when all that is displayed is the background. The weird thing is you can just refresh the page and eventually it will load. Any help you could give on what is causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: confirming an issue. After refreshing page multiple times, once i got white screen. Firebug console was showing that browser `Aborted` load of the jQuery after 53ms, and that just stopped page from farther loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console log gives this error:

"Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: note"

Looks like you've got a bad psuedo selector. Searching your js, I found this after reading the error on console:

```
$('video:note(.fullscreen),audio')
```

If you wrote this line, I'd suggest targeting a different way or target the class. If you didn't, it looks like it deals with "mediaelement-and-player" so disable that if you can.

Comment: This could also be a typo and should be using the selector :not which is a real selector.

Comment: I cannot figure out where that line actually is.  Do you know?

Comment: I found this inside widgetkit-57565c13.js which is a compressed file. Looks like the plugin is widgetkit.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  I just had to disable the mediaplayer.php page and it was all good!